# apache doesn't accept this htaccess rewrite rule

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

For some reason Apache is throwing an error if I use this rewrite rule in my `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /controller.php?lang=en&page=$1 [NE,QSA,L]
```

What I want to achieve is the following:
If the user hits

```
https://www.mywebsite.com/whatever
```

I want to call

```
https://www.mywebsite.com/controller.php?lang=en&page=whatever
```

Here's the error I get:

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@mywebsite.com
>   to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you
>   performed just before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.
>
> Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while
>   trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: Look into the `error.log` for details. Possibly enable the rewrite log as well. Also this rule is too generic and going to recurse.

Comment: ok found the problem, the rewritten url was matching again the rule causing an infinite loop

Comment: Either strip the leading target `/` or use the `[END]` flag. Better yet use something more fitting than `(.*)`, such as `\w+`